# Are Socket/DataOutputStream/DataInputStream Parcelable?

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, parcelable

I am writing an application in android studio and I want to pass data using Intent.putExtra(). To do this I need the object to implement Parcelable. The problem is that my object has variables like Socket or DataOutputStream. To implemenet Parcelable I need the variables to be parcelable as well.

My question is: Are Socket and DataOutputStream/DataInputStream are parcelable? And if not how can I pass them between two activities in android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. The arguments that you put into an `Intent` as "extras" need to be able to be serialized to a byte stream and stored persistently outside of your application. Android does this in case it needs to kill the OS Process hosting your application. When Android creates a new OS Process it will then reinstantiate your components and pass in the `Intent` with those extras.

Because of this you cannot pass sockets or streams like this.

Just store a reference to your socket or stream in a `static` variable and this can be "shared" directly by multiple components, like "global variables".